# TinyMCE 3 - parent div on blur

Tags: jquery, html, tinymce, blur

how to find attr from a parent div on blur in editor?

```
function loadEditor(){
    tinymce.init({
        selector: "textarea",
        toolbar: "fullscreen | undo redo | styleselect | bold italic underline | link image",
        menubar : false,
        statusbar : false,
        plugins : 'fullscreen autolink link image',
        setup: function(editor) {
            editor.on('blur', function(e) {
                alert($(this).parent().attr("data-id"));
            });
        }
    }); 
}
```

HTML

```
<div data-id="5"><textarea name="editor"></textarea></div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I asume you want to find the parent div of the textarea that gets transformed into a tinymce editor.

Here is the way to go (see this fiddle too: http://fiddle.tinymce.com/mHdaab).

```
setup : function(ed) {
    ed.onInit.add( function(ed) {
        tinymce.dom.Event.add(ed.getDoc(), 'blur', function(e) {
            var parent = document.getElementById(ed.id).parentNode;
            console.log('parent', parent);
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
alert($(this).parent().data("id"));
```